# max() arg is empty error when joining strings

Tags: python, join

I'm new to coding and I was trying to make a script that will join the tuples inside 'sl', which are a sequence of letters, into a new tuple called 's' with the items as strings. and then print out the longest string inside s.

this is the code I came up with (or short version). When I try to print the max item of 's' in this code, returns a

> max() arg is empty

error.

```
sl = [['m','o','o','n'],['d','a','y'],['h','e','l','l','o']]
s = []

s = (''.join(i) for i in sl) # join the letters inside sl, put them into s

print(max(s, key=len)) # print longest string inside s
```

but I still can iterate throught s with:

```
for i in s:
    print(i)
```

and will print the words inside s, joined

I suppose that (''.join(i) for i in sl) isnt properly joining them as strings. Is there a way that the words inside 's' are join as strings?

Comment: you did an ok job. The "problem" is that `s` is not a container object (list, tuple, set, dictionary) but rather a generator. if you do instead `s = [''.join(i) for i in sl]` (replace parentheses with brackets) it will work

Comment: It can also work with `s` as a generator by modifying the way you define the `key` as: `print(max(s, key=lambda x: len(x)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, just replace `()` with `[]`

```
sl = [['m','o','o','n'],['d','a','y'],['h','e','l','l','o']]

s = []

s = [''.join(i) for i in sl] 

print(s)

print(max(s, key=len))
```